# Android drawables; poor performance issue

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, drawing, android-framelayout

In order to create a shaded bevel effect, I've created a drawable xml file which is applied as the 'Foreground' property of various FrameLayouts.

I have three FrameLayouts on the screen with this drawable as their Foreground, one of which contains a Google map, and I've noticed a big drop in performance (evident by interacting with the Google map) caused by the drawable. Commenting the entire drawable lists with  restores normal performance.

Admittedly the drawable does quite a lot (seven shapes, with subtly different colours and blending, in order to create a nice shaded bevel reminiscent of '80s military interfaces). Presumably Android is performing the whole lot per drawing operation, instead of caching and reusing the result?

Can anyone suggest how to retain the visual functionality, but improve performance?

The drawable file:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="@dimen/BevelInset"
        android:top="@dimen/BevelInset"
        android:bottom="@dimen/BevelInset"
        android:right="@dimen/BevelInset">
        <shape
               android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:radius="@dimen/BevelRadius" />
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/BevelEdge"
                android:color="@color/ViewBevelColour" />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/TransparentColour" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="@dimen/BevelInset"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:right="0dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:radius="5dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="@color/ViewBevelDarkColour" />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/TransparentColour" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="@dimen/BevelInset"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:right="0dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:radius="@dimen/BevelRadius" />
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/BevelEdge"
                android:color="@color/ViewBevelDarkColour" />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/TransparentColour" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="@dimen/BevelInset"
        android:right="0dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:radius="@dimen/BevelRadius" />
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/BevelEdge"
                android:color="@color/ViewBevelLightColour" />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/TransparentColour" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:right="@dimen/BevelInset">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:radius="@dimen/BevelRadius" />
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/BevelEdge"
                android:color="@color/ViewBevelLightColour" />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/TransparentColour" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="@dimen/BevelBlend"
        android:top="@dimen/BevelBlend"
        android:bottom="@dimen/BevelBlend"
        android:right="@dimen/BevelBlend">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:radius="@dimen/BevelRadius" />
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/BevelEdge"
                android:color="@color/ViewBevelBlendColour" />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/TransparentColour" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
               android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/BevelEdge"
                android:color="@color/ViewBevelColour" />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/TransparentColour" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The style values:

```
<resources>
    <color name="ViewBevelColour">#ff004f4f</color>
    <color name="ViewBevelDarkColour">#3f000000</color>
    <color name="ViewBevelLightColour">#3fffffff</color>
    <color name="ViewBevelBlendColour">#7f004f4f</color>
    <color name="BackgroundColour">#ff000000</color>
    <color name="TransparentColour">#00ffffff</color>
    <dimen name="BevelInset">3dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="BevelEdge">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="BevelRadius">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="BevelBlend">1dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="BevelTotal">8dp</dimen>
    <color name="DividerColour">#ff00ff00</color>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/BackgroundColour</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffff0000</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: I guess a 9 patch would be faster.

Comment: Just had a go with that; I seem to lose the transparency unfortunately (the rounded edges dictate that I must use this as a partially transparent foreground).

Comment: 9 patches aren't so intuitive, at the beginning. Try reading this document: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/